# Can I set the order of the Tags in a Question?

Tags: feature-request

When I view a Question, the heading in the tab of my browser begins with the most popular of the Tags attached to the Question. For example: [Are There Other People](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10350/are-there-other-people-according-to-buddhism) has the word philosophy - then the Title of the Question. I want "Nonduality" (a recently created Tag) to show instead, but it won't do that unless it is the only Tag.

Why doesn't it show the first Tag first? In other words, why sort the Tags in the Question and its display by popularity? **Can *I* not determine what is most important?**

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109531/how-do-i-edit-the-order-of-tags-on-a-question &  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question  These say that the tags are sorted. I am asking to override that to make a little-known tag more visible.

Comment: SE Meta feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261277/set-most-important-tag-so-that-it-shows-in-title-when-searching-and-tab-of-brows

Answer (score 1):

Sorry as you've found out the tags aren't orderable and Buddhism SE can't change that. I really appreciate that you care about the [non-duality](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-duality) tag. Thank you for that. It's people taking an interest in the site that make it what it is. In order to improve the tag you could

1. Provide or enhance a tag description.
2. Edit existing questions to include the tag if appropriate to that question
3. Edit the tag to provide links to some good examples of the tag.

Just suggestions. I'm happy to provide any help needed. I'll look out for any questions that might benefit from this tag.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help and suggestions. There is a tag description. I could add links. Not sure what questions to add it to, but I will watch for any.